# How to setup multiple screens in qt mainwindow

Tags: qt, qt5, qmainwindow

I am developing a Hospital Management System using Qt.  It has options to create Patients, edit Patients and generate Bills.  I used a QMainWindow and had three buttons in the Toolbar for each of these three options.  Now when user selects one of these three buttons I want to load the form corresponding to that , foreg., Patient Creation Form or Patient Edit form and so on.. In QtDesigner for QMainWindow I was able to design one form based on the center widget.  How to design multiple form and load them over center widget based on user action.

Answer (score 2):

```
Add New -> Qt Designer Form Class
```

Set name of your class, mark `"Create form"`, inherit `QDialog`. Create your dialog using Qt Designer or do it by code and call it in MainWindow like this:

```
MyDialog dlg;
dlg.show();
```

To communicate between `MainWindow` and your forms (for example send new data to your `MainWindow`) you should use signals and slots.

If your forms should create and edit some data, you can do it modal. `setModal` method

Answer (score 1):

you should use [QStackedWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html)

> The QStackedWidget class provides a stack of widgets where only one
>   widget is visible at a time.

It's possible to manage stacked widgets by index or by their pointers.